# Credit Card Gateway? - API, Price

Tags: .net

We are looking for Credit Card gateway for our new project. There is mess out there, all just try to cut you in pieces. Everytime i talk to them they have different rate and every time they update quote they have some price changed.

**We are having this project in .net, C#, asp.net.**

**So considering above this what could be the best gateway option for us?**

How much is usual rate for large number of processing(around 2000 transaction a day)

Any insight is helpful.

Comment: Make sure you look for long-term commitments in whatever contract you sign. Early termination fees suck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of factors and we can't answer that for you, but maybe this will help.

A particular (popular) shopping cart has a poll on their forums asking which gateway their customers use, so you can look at their poll results to see what's popular, at least for their customers.

http://forums.aspdotnetstorefront.com/showthread.php?t=8016

When we were choosing, our top choices, based on price, support, reputability, and ease of integration were (in no particular order)

- google chekout
- paypal
- Authorize.Net
- Bank of America (via Cybersource).

Answer (score 2):

I used to be set up with Authorize.Net.  Their XML-RPC Gateway is pretty cake to use.  I remember discount rates around 2.8% + $.50 per transaction or something like that.  That is the combined fees from the Merchant Company and Authorize.Net.  Auth.Net approves the transactions and the Merchant Company deposits the funds to your bank.

Comment: I've have also setup authorize.net merchant apps in the past. Rates were acceptable (better than some). Their support was very helpful in troubleshooting when I ran into issues initially. So I 2nd Auth.net...

Answer (score 2):

A few places I have worked have used [preCharge](https://www.precharge.com/). They have really great fraud screening and can either work with an existing merchant account or provide a merchant account for you.

I have personally used [First National Merchant Solutions](http://www.firstnationalmerchants.com) through [PayPal's PayFlow Pro](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_payflow-pro-overview-outside) with good results. PayPal purchased the PayFlow Pro service from VeriSign.

If you want to get started without a lot of hassle you could take a look at [SWREG](http://www.swreg.org/), which is one of the ecommerce providers owned by [Digital River](http://www.digitalriver.com).

Answer (score 1):

I have used PayPal in one of my projects. I don't remember their rate, but you can check their site.

They have a lot of samples on how to use their system, including asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

Paypal and Google Checkout are both incredibly reputable and don't use shady sales techniques to scam you out of extra money.  They're both fairly straightforward, and both easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used them, but a while back I heard very good things about [braintree payment solutions](http://www.braintreepaymentsolutions.com/) -- one of their big sales messages is transparent, honest, pricing.  They also have some cool PCI compliance features if you need to store credit card data.